# How to make Chrome not load from cache, while cache is disabled?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, browser-cache

Chrome keeps loading an image from cache, even when I have the dev tools open, and have disabled cache.

[image: uwotm9]

Why does Chrome do this?

How to make it stop?

Answer (score 0):

The image you're loading is a [base64 encoded inline image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images). That means it's no loaded via a separate HTTP request, but instead is embedded inside your HTML, CSS or JavaScript code.

The URL could look like this for example: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG....

[image: Fetching base64 image]

Chrome is treating it as a request to a `data:` url, but since no server roundtrip is required to look it up Chrome shows it as "(from cache)". (This isn't quite accurate but does make some sense.)